# How many users did we get from Reddit?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

[DavRob60](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/45/davrob60) posted [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6238/3804) on Reddit. And we suddenly had a huge explosion of views.

Did this translate into any new users?

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking at the stats, and while there was a bit higher anon voting going on, I don't think there is actually a huge increase of users. The new users looks like a typical day, although perhaps a bit on the higher end. Not sure about compensating for the day of the week, which usually makes a difference. Still, stuff like this tends to increase the google power, and will no doubt result in a few new users at some point in time, but I don't see a huge direct benefit, unfortunately. Of course, you never really know, so...

Answer (score 1):

So the TIL post was timestamped `Fri Aug 3 12:48:13 2012 UTC`.

Looking at our [users list sorted by creation date](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?page=1&tab=newusers&sort=creationdate), I looked at each user's creation time until I found the first one after that timestamp: [logoff](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/8098/logoff), who registered at `2012-08-03 12:53:39Z` (`Z` being shorthand for UTC, so there's timezone agreement).

So, that means 36 new user accounts were registered after the TIL post was created. Of those 36:

- 11 already had accounts elsewhere on the network (they got the 100 rep association bonus)
- 5 actively contributed to gain reputation

The user list doesn't track unregistered users, though, and I've seen several around the site today. I vaguely remember the moderator tools having something that can track those.

Comment: Mods do have such tools, but we couldn't give an exact number, so...

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto Right, but you could give a general ballpark, n'est-ce pas? A couple dozen? Hundreds?

Comment: @MarkTrapp Although not a mod, so I don't have the tools, I'd guess 42.