# What is the point in the community promotion ads that go to *this* site?

Tags: discussion, advertising

I was under the impression that the community promotion ads are shown **only on this site**

If that is so, can we remove the ones that send us in a circular loop:

- https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2253/3383
- https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2252/3383
- https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2251/3383

Comment: For that matter, is it really necessary to have a gajillion ads for the blog?

Comment: @MarkTrapp that too... but I wasn't going to bring that up....

Comment: @MarkTrapp Yes.

Comment: @MarkTrapp as a follow up, I had asked members in the chat room to create ads to promote the blog and to help inspire people to want to contribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None.

Ads for the blogs are relevant, though the blog posts already show up in the community bulletin. (What, you don't pay attention to the community bulletin? You and just about everyone else.)

Ads for the site on the site are useless.

If you want to advertise SF&F, advertise it on *other* Stack Exchange sites, or outside Stack Exchange. Note that beta sites don't have ads. None of the graduated sites is very relevant; [RPG](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/), maybe, and perhaps even [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/).

On SF&F, you may want to advertise for other sites or Area 51 proposals.

Comment: So can those posts be removed?

Comment: I think there's some CSS flaw with community bulletin. I easily notice it on SO daily, even though I visit it much rarer than SFF, but until reading this post, I don't think I ever even noticed that there was one on SFF.

Comment: ... and I know what the flaw is, at least for me. Black background, same as site borders. I'm conditioned to ignore black background on SFF :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to consider the instructions on the original [Community Promotion Ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14902/slow-down-selfish-users?rq=1) post.

1. Nowhere on the post is the issue of the clickthrough URL addressed.
2. The post says the ads will be featured on the main page of SE, making the scifi.stackexchange.com URL logical as a clickthrough.
3. Nowhere on the post does it say the ads were now going to be featured on SFF itself, which of course makes scifi.stackexchange.com the incorrect clickthrough URL.
4. There are no example suggestions for clickthrough URLs to indicate this change.

Since I used scifi.stackexchange.com on my first ad way back in January, and with a lack of any updated information, I *didn't know* to change the clickthrough URL. It didn't say the ads were going to be featured on SFF and not on the main SE page, as it was before. When I checked this morning, the original post was still in place.

I think it helps to build our community to extend the benefit of the doubt and to try and help our fellow users where we can. For example:

A user codes the wrong clickthrough URL on a community promo ad. One could:

1. Go through every banner ad submission the user has made and comment with "Why is your ad leading back to scifi.stackexchange.com?" on *every single post*, without any further information or any offer to help.
2. Leave a comment on one of the banner ad posts saying, "It looks like you've got the wrong URL on your clickthrough -- do you need some help?" Or ping the user in chat to let him/her know there's a problem.

or:

1. Make an entire meta post pointing out the user's mistake and asking for the user's posts to be removed. Not fixed. But **removed**.
2. Leave a comment on one of the user's posts saying, "Hey, I see you've got your URLs wrong in posts X, Y, Z -- do you need a hand figuring it out?"

Just some alternate reactions for consideration. I myself am not a programmer, so even the few lines of code in the community promo ads were something I had to actively figure out. In this regard, it would also be great if someone would update the original post with more specific information regarding the clickthrough URLs.

Comment: Few points: 1) regarding (2) and (3) in your first ordered list, yes it does. Second paragraph: "Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar." 2) Regarding (4), [yes there is](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/992/366). 3) Regarding the rest of your post, the ads in question weren't people just messing up the format of the click-through URL: they were advertising SciFi.SE. That is, the click-through URLs were correct; the ads were just misguided. This question was just calling attention to that: no harm, no foul.

Comment: *Whatever* it was that was wrong in the ads my main point was there was a kinder, more friendly way to handle my mistakes. That's what I wanted to point out. We're supposed to be a community. I'm so glad, Mark, that no harm or foul was done to you. However, you don't get to dictate how it affected me. It's not like I'm all over this board screaming about being wronged all the time. *All* the ads were advertising SFF ... why were mine the only ones that were misguided? And the original post complains specifically about the URLs leading back to SFF ... what are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the one who posted the first one, so here was my reasoning.

I posted [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6238/did-tolkien-really-explicitly-consider-sam-the-true-hero-of-lotr) on Reddit a friday and this lead to a whooping 90k view before the weekend ended. But further inspection made me think we didn't get too many new users from it, see : [How many users did we get from Reddit?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2108/how-many-users-did-we-get-from-reddit)

So my idea was to keep potential new users that come from search engines or Reddit on the site.

Was it a good idea? Well, there is not enough support for these add yet, so I guess is it was not that good.