# A call to arms! I mean Ads for Gaming.Stackexchange!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

> There are many of us on Arqade who would [very much like to offload some of the "lore" questions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5325/why-did-people-vote-to-close-this-question-about-harbinger-in-me3) [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2258/what-is-the-point-in-the-community-promotion-ads-that-go-to-this-site#comment5515_2259), so advertising [there](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3352/community-promotion-ads-2012) would definitely be good. – [Mark Trapp](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/366/mark-trapp)

I've posted on Arqade about this issue, [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5339/16142).

## Can anyone design a decent ad for them/us?

**Some guidelines:**

1. We'd like 6 upvotes before putting it forward to their ad thread.
2. We'd like you to link to a relevant question this site.

Comment: I can try. What did you want it to look like?

Comment: Someone absolutely MUST do an ad with the words "All your lore question are belong to us!". (perhapes prefixed with "somebody set us up a SciFi&Fantasy Stack Exchange site"

Comment: And, just to piss off everyone who doesn't hate OLD memes: "I used to not know where to get answers to my lore questions. But then I took an SFF.SE arrow to the knee". </troll>

Comment: I think referencing a specific question (with a topical image and text) would be more useful in hooking people.

Answer (score 9):

[image: I'm Commander Shepard]

Comment: As per Gilles suggestion: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10484/why-do-the-aliens-in-mass-effect-have-breasts

Comment: @Pureferret A suggestion? To change the link?

Comment: Yeah, though only a suggestion, linking to the tags should be ok too.

Comment: @Pureferret I am ok with whatever link seems best. If/when it hits 6 UV feel free to use whichever you want when copying it to Arqade.

Comment: I'll see if the link gets upvoted too.

Comment: I don't know about others, but I feel that it needs a visual indication on it that it's for a different site.  I'd see that and just assume it's something meaningless like those "web awards" or something saying "hey, Gaming.SE is cool!"

Comment: @dlanod Like that?

Comment: @Xantec Yep, upvoted. :)

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Should I post this on their community ad page? Or where should I put this?

Comment: On there community ads page.

Comment: I think first we should up-vrte it though.

Comment: It should be gaming related. This is LOTR, not primarily a game.

Comment: There's several LOTR games! And its punny!

Comment: @bitmask and thus we wait and vote

Answer (score 7):

[image: Scientist. Fictional.]

Comment: If the community approves I will post it on arqade.

Comment: Do we want 6 to put it on Gaming?

Comment: @Pureferret: Makes sense. Although it should apply to all suggestions. It should be in the OP.

Comment: Yay, sixth upvote! Nice ad, by the way. Good work!

Comment: As per Gilles suggestion: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15796/what-is-the-link-between-the-portal-series-and-half-life-series

Answer (score 6):

[image: Ask your lore questions on scifi.stackexchange]

Comment: As per Gilles suggestion: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games+portal?sort=newest&pagesize=30 go nuts

Comment: I'm a nit-picking monster sometimes and you are allowed to tell me to shut up, but the text doesn't seem properly aligned in the upper text. Nit-pick #2: triple dots must be preceded by a space. Having said all that: **I bloody love this!**

Comment: I'm not nitpicking, I just love it. :D

Comment: Updated, in addition for bitmask's improvements, I replaced the font by Lucidia Console, to get a computer feels.

Answer (score 4):

[image: The Evolution of the Combine Strider]

Comment: I challenge you to get any sillier!

Comment: For reference: [The Combine Strider](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Strider)

Comment: Oh, that's excellent! I like it.

Comment: @SaintWacko: It's more a joke, actually :)

Comment: Doesn't matter, still like it :)